# What's the single best reference on the topic of (POSIX) signals?

Tags: c, linux, unix, posix, signals

Signals seem to be one of those areas that should be conceptually simple and easy to explain but I have never come across one source that is both comprehensive, lucidly written, and up to date.  In part this seems to be because of historical cruft, lots of exceptions to rules, different programming standards, the confusion threads throw into the mix, real-time additions, etc.

What's your best written, most complete source on unix/linux/posix signals?  Web sites, books, stone tablets, whatever, are acceptable.

Comment: Might care for "man 2 sigaction"

Answer (score 2):

Maybe not *comprehensive* or *lucid*, but the following is generally *up to date* for your platform:

```
man signal
```

Comment: Man pages are what they are but I was hoping for something more expository.

Comment: Yes, I was a little "tongue in cheek" here. I guess my message is that books can give you a good understanding, but when you have to actually implement, look at the man pages.

Comment: And I guess that man pages are generally *comprehensive* as well. It is the *lucid* part where they often fail.

Answer (score 2):

[Advanced Programming in the UNIX Environment](http://www.apuebook.com/) (you may see it referred to as APUE).

Comment: I have the 1st edition (1992) but it is a bit long in the tooth.  Do you know if the signals chapter was significantly updated in the 2nd edition from a couple of years ago?

Comment: Not sure what was changed between the two.  The 2nd edition's chapter on signals is 65 pages and has 20 sections (plus an intro and a summary for a total of 22 sections).  You can see the titles of the sections in the online table of contents (http://www.apuebook.com/toc.html).

Answer (score 2):

Re: the comments to check man pages: Whenever I encounter man page failure (wrt either lucidity or completeness), I hit up OpenBSD's version.  At least nine times out of ten, it's a night and day difference.

So my suggestion in this case is [man sigaction](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man2/sigaction.2) & [man signal](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man3/signal.3).

Answer (score 1):

Not the clearest documentation, but it's free and comprehensive: the UNIX spec at opengroup.org.

Section 2.4 Signal Concepts: http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/xsh_chap02_04.html

Answer (score 1):

The POSIX signal reference page, by OpenGroup+IEEE:

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/signal.html

I take it that since you mentioned POSIX in brackets, you don't really want a formal POSIX conformance necessarily, but many of the people (me including) searching for "posix signal reference" end up with your question high up there in the results, and I hope the link takes them to what they are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

W. Richard Stevens is hard to beat on most things UNIX. I own at least 5 of his books and I think they are classics that should be on any UNIX System Programmer's shelf. Cheers.

UNIX Network Programming, Vol 2. Second Edition here [http://www.amazon.com/UNIX-Network-Programming-Interprocess-Communications/dp/0130810819](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0130810819)

Comment: Stevens is always great but he really only devotes a half dozen or so pages - and bunch of little references spread around the book - to signals in that volume.  I was hoping for some a little more centralized and detailed.