# man page with list of posix signals?

Tags: signals, posix, manpage

Is there a man page with the list of posix signals?

On Linux, neither `kill` nor `signal` man pages have the list, nor was I able to find an enum definition on `/usr/include`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the single best reference on the topic of (POSIX) signals?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419258/whats-the-single-best-reference-on-the-topic-of-posix-signals)

Comment: Seems like the answer is to use openbsd version of the manpages.

Comment: I read (and fixed) many of the links on that page and that definitely seemed like the best resource for listing signals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Section 7 of manual gives the list of signals. Use:

```
man 7 signal
```